# SimpleDateFormat parsing wrong date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Here I am trying to compare 3 dates, for that, I have passed a date and two string to a function. And I am using simple date format to make 3 dates of the same format so that I can compare them. But for the two string value, I am getting the wrong date when I parse it. Can anyone please help?

```
Private boolean compareDate(Date cdate, String fdate, String date) {
    //cdate = 2020-03-25 09:05:47
    //fdate = 03/10/2020
    //tdate = 03/25/2020

    SimpleDateFormat sd= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String s=sd.format(cdate);
    Date d1=sd.parse(s);
    Date d2=sd.parse(fdate);
    Date d3=sd.parse(tdate);
}
```

The values that I get after parsing is :

```
D1 = wed Mar 25 00:00:00 IST 2020
D2 = sat Oct 03 00:00:00 IST 2020 //wrong date fdate was 03/10/2020
D3 = Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 IST2020 //wrong date  tdate was 03/25/2020
```

Can anyone tell where did I go wrong? And due to this issue, I am not able to properly compare them.

Comment: Hey! Please format your question properly. It's not rocket science.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Could you please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Including, make sure that your code can compile? It’s much easier to spot a bug like yours when I can run your code at and see it happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate 
.toInstant()
.atZone
(
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) 
)
.toLocalDate()
.isEqual
(
    LocalDate
    .parse
    (
        "03/10/2020" ,                              // Do you mean March 10th, or October 3rd? 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) // Or "MM/dd/uuuu".
    )
)
```

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

You said:

> make 3 dates of the same format so that I can compare them

Use objects with comparison methods, rather than comparing text of strings.

We have a class for dates built into Java: `LocalDate`.

## *java.time*

You are using `Date` which is one of the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These classes are now obsolete, supplanted years ago with the adoption of JSR 310 that defines the *java.time* classes.

> I have passed a date

When encountering a `java.util.Date` object, immediately convert to its modern replacement, `java.time.Instant`. Use the new conversion method [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#toInstant()) added to the old class.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Both `java.util.Date` and `java.time.Instant` represent a moment in UTC. Is that how you want to perceive the date, in UTC with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the prime meridian? Keep in mind that for any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone. A moment may be "tomorrow" in Tokyo Japan while still "yesterday" in Toledo Ohio US.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Extract the date.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;  // Extract the date only, omitting the time-of-day and the offset-from-UTC.
```

Or did you want to perceive that date in a particular zone?

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;  // Extract the date only, omitting the time-of-day and the zone.
```

> and two string to a function

Define a formatting pattern to match your inputs.

```
String input = "03/10/2020" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;  // Throws `DateTimeParseException` if input is faulty.
```

Now compare, using methods [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)), `isAfter`, `isBefore`.

```
boolean datesMatch = ld1.isEqual( ld2 ) && ld2.isEqual( ld3 ) ;
```

## `java.util.Date::toString` tells a lie

You asked:

> `D2 = sat Oct 03 00:00:00 IST 2020 //wrong date fdate was 03/10/2020`
>
> Can anyone tell where did I go wrong?

Your main problem is that your formatting pattern is not defined to match your intention. This is correctly identified in the [Answer by Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60858122/642706) and the [Answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60858708/642706).

In addition, you have another issue. Among the many problems with `java.util.Date` is that its `toString` method on-the-fly applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating text to represent the content of the object. This creates the illusion of that zone being stored within the object. When perceiving your `Date` object’s UTC value after adjusting to a time zone, the date may differ from the date as seen in UTC. This was discussed above.

**➥ Never use `java.util.Date`.**

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

Your format is day then month then year, but presumably your strings are month then day then year, looking at tDate, which has 25 in the middle and so cannot be a month

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the mismatch in the format and the date strings. Your formatter is as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat sd= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

whereas your date strings e.g. `03/10/2020` or `03/25/2020` are in `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

Change either of them to match the other one.

I also recommend you use [Modern date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) instead of broken `Date` and  `SimpleDateFormat`classes.